# my web application is hung when the number of connections exceed the maxSize of pool

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, connection-pooling

I'm working with tomcat 7, after run the application and made some requests let's say at most 13 requests, after that the system is enter in the freezing status, there are no exceptions in the console and there is no specific place this status occurs in it.

Comment: Are you releasing the connection back to the pool? Sorry without code we cant help much!

Comment: thanks for replay, but as I said there is no specific place this status occurs in it. but what did you mean by releasing the connection?

Comment: There is no exception because it Waits until a connection is available. In this case presumably for ever ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the connection back to the pool, to do that you can use the annotation `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)` when you call your `DAO`.